# Div positioning in float going out of frame

Tags: css

[image]

I am looking to create a similar widget on my page https://kunalaren.com/about-me/
My subscription div is falling out of place. I need to align it in the same way as it is shown in the image.

Width of each div is set to 50% and 1,3 and 2,4 child of .cta are supposed to be float in left and right respectively.

Any help is appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="cta">
<div> <p>Double Your Sales Today!</p></div>

<div><p>Use the form below to open his daily email tips and free consultation worth $97.</p></div>

<div><p>Leader of SEO and Digital Marketing is Giving Away Tips For Doubling Sales Right Now!</p></div>
<div>[contact-form-7 id="125" title="Subscribe"]</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.cta{
    background-color:white;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
}

.cta div:nth-child(1){
width:50%;
float:left;
}
.cta div:nth-child(1) > p{
margin:0px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-bottom:10px;
    display:inline-block;
font-weight:bolder;
font-size:40px;
color:black;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

div.cta div:nth-child(2){
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
div.cta div:nth-child(2)>p{
color:black;
    text-align:center;
font-family: 'Style Script', cursive;
margin:0px;
font-size:40px;
background-color:#ffc569;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:5px;
}
div.cta div:nth-child(3)>p{
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;

}
div.cta div:nth-child(3){
    width:50%;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed',serif;
padding-left:25px;
}

div.cta div:nth-child(4){
float:right;
width:50%;
margin-top:0px;
}
/*******Mob. Responsive***/

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
    div.cta div:nth-child(n),div.cta div:nth-child(n)>p{
         float:none;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        padding-left:0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<div class="cta">
 <div class="half"> 
  <p>Double Your Sales Today!</p>
  <p>Use the form below to open his daily email tips and free 
     consultation worth $97.
  </p>
 </div>

 <div class="half">
  <p>Leader of SEO and Digital Marketing is Giving Away Tips For 
  Doubling 
     Sales Right Now!
  </p>
  <div>[contact-form-7 id="125" title="Subscribe"]</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cta {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}

.half {
 flex: 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed some styling, but grid should work ok

```css
.cta {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}


.clear {
 clear: both;
}

.cta-left, .cta-inner-left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.cta-right, .cta-inner-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.cta-left > p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}

.cta-right > p {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Style Script", cursive;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ffc569;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
}

/*******Mob. Responsive***/

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .cta-left,
  .cta-right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cta">
  <div class="cta-left">
    <p>Double Your Sales Today!</p>
    <div class="cta-inner">
      <div class="cta-inner-left">

          Leader of SEO and Digital Marketing is Giving Away Tips For Doubling
          Sales Right Now!

      </div>
      <div class="cta-inner-right">[contact-form-7 id="125" title="Subscribe"]</div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-right">
    <p>
      Use the form below to open his daily email tips and free consultation
      worth $97.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```